# Is anyone able to pull the ShippingLatitude and ShippingLongitude data?

Tags: account, query

I look at the Account API and I've seen these two new beta fields.  How can I access the data of these two fields?

ShippingLatitude 
ShippingLongitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set you API version to 30.0 so you can access the Spring 14 release features. You can then query them with SOQL.

E.g.

```
Select Id,ShippingLatitude,ShippingLongitude from Account
```

[image]

[ShippingLatitude](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm#shippingLatitude) is a double in the range of -90 to 90 and is stored to 15 decimal places.

[ShippingLongitude](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm#shippingLongitude) is a double in the range -180 to 180 and is stored to 15 decimal places.